# ultravnc inserts leading and trailing characters into copy paste

Tags: vnc

I select and copy paste something (even inside the same window) and somebody inserts leading and trailing characters. e.g. I select "abc" and paste this and it ends up as "00~abc01~".

This happens only since about a week.
I only changed the terminal from which I started the server.

Comment: Are you entering special/non-latin or accented characters?

Comment: no -- normal filenames and output...

Answer (score 0):

I only now found out. The originating terminal had the language set to C. Changing this back to en_US.UTF-8 fixed this issue...